# How to change the Texture Type of a .png image to Sprite through a script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and I have a lot of images in the Resource folder. I am saving these images using my nodejs and MySQL server.

What I need to do is that when reading those images, I change the Texture Type to "Sprite" through a script (by default is set to "Default"), since it is necessary that they have a Texture Type "Sprite" to be able to put the image in a canvas.

I know that it can be done using the Unity inspector but I need to do it with a script, since I don't know which images are going to be in what quantity.

Greetings.
[inspector configuration on an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRFrm.png)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to create a sprite from texture. So you can use Sprite.Create function here I add a function from which you can convert texture to sprite.

```
public static Sprite TextureToSprite(Texture2D texture) => Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 50f, 0, SpriteMeshType.FullRect);
```

you can call like this

```
var sprite = TextureToSprite(yourTexture);
```

now you can use this sprite in the canvas image component.
**NOTE** :- You can change Sprite.Create functions parameters according to your need.

Comment: Docs here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html